# Mongodb display number of distinct entries per entry

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I would like to be able to list the following

**Data**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "name" : "Dash"
}
/* 2 */
{
    "name" : "Dash"
}
/* 3 */
{
    "name" : "Pink"
}
/* 4 */
{
    "name" : "Pink"
}
/* 1 */
{
    "name" : "Jamie"
}
```

What I can currently get with `db.getCollection('players').distinct('name')`:

```
/* 1 */
[
    "Dash",
    "Pink",
    "Jamie"
]
```

What I would like:

```
/* 1 */
[
    {
       name: "Dash",
       number: 2
    }
    {
       name: "Pink",
       number: 2
    }
    {
       name: "Jamie",
       number: 1
    }
]
```

Is this possible with mongo?

Comment: Yes is possible use `aggregation`, `group` and `sum` you will get your expected result

Comment: `db.players.aggregate(
   [
      { $group: { _id: "$name", number: { $sum: 1 } } }
   ]
)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is certainly possible with MongoDB's aggregate commands. What you are looking for is a $group aggregation (https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/group/).

From these groupings you can set the name as the _id and use the `$sum` operation to include the counts. An example shell command would be:

```
db.players.aggregate([{
    $group : {
       _id : { name: "$name" },
       number: { $sum: 1 }
    }
}])
```

This would return the groupings as needed. For more information click the link I gave and look at the example :) cheers